# Proving that $2^n > 1 + n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Prove that  $2^n > 1 + n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$ using AM-GM(/HM).

My attempt:

$1+2^1> 2\sqrt{2}$ //Using AM-GM

$1+2^2 > 2\sqrt{2^2} ... \\ 1+2^n > 2\sqrt{2^n}$

Adding all the inequalities gives: $n+(2^1+...+2^n)> 2({\sqrt2+...+\sqrt{2^n}})$

Then I used sum of terms in GP's formula and rearranged but couldn't arrive at the desired answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{2^n-1}{n}=\frac{1+2+4+\ldots+2^{n-1}}{n}\geqslant \root n \of {2^{0+1+\ldots+(n-1)}}=2^{\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=\sqrt{2^{n-1}}
$$